# Shape Of A Blimp.

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

Was playing around with solids of revolution, the shape given by rotating $y=\sqrt{\sin x}$ about the $x-$axis seems to resemble a blimp.

[image]

[image]

The only thing I can find out about the natural shape of the blimp is that it is formed by the pressure of the lifting gas.  Any reason a sinusoidal relationship should emerge from this?

Comment: Do you mean to express a mathematical model for the blimp that explains that how the shape is formed? :)

Comment: http://www.airships.net/lz127-graf-zeppelin/design-technology I don't think that is a sinusoid.

Comment: @JohnDouma: Interesting Link! :)

Comment: @H.R. Yes, that would be nice.

Comment: So, I assume you are looking for some differential equation which is the result of the model and its answer is $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$. :) At the top of my head, I remember such models are discussed in solid-fluid interactions in fluid dynamics but I cannot recall the whole thing. :) However, I cannot assure that you will have some sinusoidal answer! :)

Comment: @johndouma I'm asking about a blimp, which does not have the metal outer skeleton like a zeppelin.

Comment: Wouldn't the shape of a blimp be determined by its design, not by physics? I mean, maybe there's some optimal shape for a blimp (when optimizing for something specific), but one could make a blimp of any shape.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Apparently the gas distribution is what determines the shape. I'm not knowledgeable about fluid mechanics, but I don't think the shape is arbitrary. Again, a blimp's outer shell is not fixed. You may be thinking of a zeppelin instead.

Comment: I thought there was a metal frame for the blimp.  No?

Comment: http://www.airships.net/dirigible

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://books.google.com/books?id=lKygBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA360&lpg=PA360&dq=mathematical+shape+of+blimp&source=bl&ots=snqrazos7J&sig=LBCq2VuRVQOR144IF-pgfS6CmmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyLTV2sPJAhWCQD4KHfWnAGc4ChDoAQgWMAQ#v=onepage&q=mathematical%20shape%20of%20blimp&f=false) gives some information about the mathematical model of a blimp surface. It seems more complicated than what I suggested in the question.